# How to get subtotal from order items collection in magento 1.9.2 community edition

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to show order details on frontend just like backend
[image]

Here is my code

```
$orderData = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
$itemCollection = $orderData->getItemsCollection();

foreach($itemsCollection as $_items) {
    echo $_items->getName();
    echo $_items->getStatus();
    echo $_items->getOriginalPrice();
    echo $_items->getPrice();
    echo $_items->getQtyOrdered();
    echo $_items->getSubTotal();
    echo $_items->getTaxAmount();
    echo $_items->getPercent();
    echo $_items->getDiscountAmount();
    echo $_items->getRowTotal();
}
```

Apart from Subtotal I am getting Everything I tried this too:

```
echo $_items->getBaseSubtotal();
```

But I am still getting null value.

Comment: same question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123358/how-to-get-subtotal-from-order-items-collection-in-magento-1-9-2-community-editi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Amit Bera's answer on Magento.SE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123358/how-to-get-subtotal-from-order-items-collection-in-magento-1-9-2-community-editi/123359#123359):

> **base_subtotal** is **field of Order table**.
>
> it is not **field to sales order item table.**.So you did not get data
> from `$_items->getBaseSubtotal()`
>
> In order to get a sales item base total try below code:
>
> > ```
> > $items->getBaseRowTotal();
> > ```